# Getting error "no suitable method to override"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying some stuff with Unity and getting lot of this error where is always "no suitable method to override". For example:

> Assets/Standard Assets/Effects/ImageEffects/Scripts/Antialiasing.cs(86,30): error CS0115: `UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects.Antialiasing.CheckResources()' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override.

Its look like that error is trivial, but I don't know C#, so don't know what with this. Can you show at this example, how fix this? Thanks!

```
public override bool CheckResources()
{
    CheckSupport(false);

    materialFXAAPreset2 = CreateMaterial(shaderFXAAPreset2, materialFXAAPreset2);
    materialFXAAPreset3 = CreateMaterial(shaderFXAAPreset3, materialFXAAPreset3);
    materialFXAAII = CreateMaterial(shaderFXAAII, materialFXAAII);
    materialFXAAIII = CreateMaterial(shaderFXAAIII, materialFXAAIII);
    nfaa = CreateMaterial(nfaaShader, nfaa);
    ssaa = CreateMaterial(ssaaShader, ssaa);
    dlaa = CreateMaterial(dlaaShader, dlaa);

    if (!ssaaShader.isSupported)
    {
        NotSupported();
        ReportAutoDisable();
    }

    return isSupported;
}
```

Comment: That's C#, not C++. Can't tell you anything about it, but changed the tags to maybe get some help.

Comment: The standard assets have quite a bit of dependencies, meaning you need mostly all files for them to work. I think perhaps you've just crossed the ones you wanted in the list and left the ones you didnt want out? Try getting all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The method in the code example you provided is marked `override`. This means that the compiler will take the class this method is in and look through the ones it inherits from to find one to override.

See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override).

If you're sure this code is correct, then removing the `override` keyword from the method definition should get rid of the error.

If you haven't written this code yourself and its part of the Unity files, then you're likely missing some dependencies (read: the files that contain the class with the method that yours should override).

Answer (score -2):

The only workaround I found was deleting the entire public class `BloomAndFlares : PostEffectsBase`. Everything else gave me an error.